# Can I mix 9.0 and 8.5 designer with 8.5.3 and 9.0.1 servers?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

We have a single server inside the firewall used for all of our production apps. The server and clients are 8.5.3.

We have a single 'portal' server outside the firewall used by a small set of our customers for read-only access to a few apps via a browser. This server is currently at 8.5.3. Mail isn't implemented on this server; customers log in, see dbs, view docs, and leave. The only admin tasks I perform on this server are to add new users and push new replicas onto the external box (which I do from my Notes client, not the admin client)

Because of POODLE, we're going to be upgrading our portal server to 9.0.1. We have no plan to upgrade our internal server (or clients).

I'm the developer and admin for both servers.

I don't intend to install the 9.0.x designer client on my system.

Do I need to install the 9.0.x admin client or can I just keep using my 8.5.3 version?

Any risks with either scenario?

Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: I don't know this exact config, but I have used server, client, admin and designer of (nearly) any version combination. Probably you cannot use brand new features in 9 from 8, but adding users should'nt be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixed versions of domino server and clients can be used and actually have been used for a long time. Certainly only the intersection set of features of these versions can be used.

Comment: Starrow, I was pretty sure this was the case. Notes has a long reputation for compatibility across versions. Since version 3.2 I've only ever had to change 1 line of code during an upgrade. My concern here had to do with losing the ability to manage a 9.x server with an 8.5 admin client; normally this works but all of the upgrade instructions call for upgrading the admin client first, then the server. Sounds like I should be OK since I'm not intending to do anything new with this server. Thanks!

Comment: Any software company would recommend upgrading its products as soon as they're available. Interesting enough that Lotus & now IBM have been giving so much priority to compatibility. I guess you would have little problem with your current combination.

Comment: Upgrades are infrequent for us. We're regulated by the FDA so any update to the client or server requires quite a bit of validation testing. We really don't need any of the new features (in fact, I would be happy going back to 6.4 and dumping Eclipse as the designer client). Our upgrades normally come every 2 versions; 4.6 to 6.5 to 8.5 so if we do upgrade again, it'll probably be at the 10.x version. The only reason we're doing this is because the server faces out and we need the POODLE fixes. Validation is not an issue since the apps are read only.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Domino servers 9 (including cluster), we are TLS because af Poodle (see [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/656610/does-my-server-still-supports-the-ssl-v3-protocol)). Most of our Client / Designer are 8.53. I recommand: do not install Client/Designer on the server (especially outside).

We had months a "last server" to upgrade (8.5) and this also didn't made problem. But I suggest to upgrade also the internal server.